# How can I add/remove a class to an element when URL contains a specific string?

Tags: jquery

I have some tabs:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" id="hometab" class="active"><a href="http://www.mypage.com/" >Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" id="contenttab"><a href="#content" aria-controls="content" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">content</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">home</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="content">content</div>
  </div>
```

And I would like to add a class to the tab, when my URL contains the string `?dir`.

So for example: if my URL is `www.mypage.com/?dir=something` then `#contenttab` should be active. And if the URL is for example only 
`www.mypage.com` then `#contenttab` should not be active but `#hometab`should be active.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = location.pathname;
    if ("url:contains('?dir')") {
        $("#contenttab").attr("class","active");
        $("#hometab").removeClass("active");

    } else {
    $("#contenttab").removeClass("active");
    $("#hometab").attr("class","active");
    }

});        
</script>
```

My script is not working. `#contenttab`is always active and `#hometab` is never active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try checking with this :

```
if ( url.indexOf( '?dir' ) !== -1 ) { ... }
```

Or try with :

```
var url = location.search; // or location.href;

if ( url.indexOf( '?dir' ) !== -1 ) { ... }
```

Comment: I tried it, and now #hometab is always active

Comment: What the value of `location.pathname`?

Comment: Yes,` location.search` worked!

Comment: Guess right, cause usually `location.pathname` only returned `/` before `?dir`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var url = location.pathname;

    if (url.indexOf('?dir') > -1) {
        $("#contenttab").attr("class", "active");
        $("#hometab").removeClass("active");

    } else {
        $("#contenttab").removeClass("active");
        $("#hometab").attr("class", "active");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but now if the URL is `http://www.mypage/?dir=something` the `#hometab` is active.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using test:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (/\?dir/.test(location.pathname)){
                $("#contenttab").attr("class","active");
                $("#hometab").removeClass("active");
            } else {
                $("#contenttab").removeClass("active");
                $("#hometab").attr("class","active");
            }
        });        
</script>
```

Thanks to the answer **[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)** I think that the best and safe way to do what you need, is to get the querystring parameter **dir**. Of course the function **getParameterByName()** will return useful to get any other querystring parameter.

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var dir=getParameterByName('dir');

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (dir==''){
        $("#contenttab").attr("class","active");
        $("#hometab").removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $("#contenttab").removeClass("active");
        $("#hometab").attr("class","active");
    }
});
```

> Note: If a parameter is present several times
>   (*?dir=lorem&dir=ipsum*), you will get the first value (lorem).

Comment: Unfortunately if the URL is `http://www.mypage/?dir=something` the `#hometab` is active.

Comment: And it's not what you want?

Comment: Know, I would need `#contenttab` to be active